# Using arcgis javascript API

Tags: javascript, api

Should I use the same function to merge points and circles?
At the moment I'm using the following function to merge points on a map application:

function mergePointGeometries(features) {
    var newgeometry = new esri.geometry.Multipoint(new esri.SpatialReference({
                wkid : 27700
            }));
    for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        var point = features[i].geometry;
        newgeometry.addPoint(point);
    }
    return newgeometry;
}

Should I include an extra function if I have a circle tool on the application so that circles can also be merged or will this do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use polygon to draw circle with passing coordinates to its constructor.